# Trying to click submit button which as image as button vba

Tags: jquery, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to click the input button on a web page using JavaScript. I have tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" src="/img/go_button.gif">
```

**VBA**

```
 ' Not working 
el.click

 ' Not working

el.focus 
el.invokemember("OnClick")
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleMenu(obj, title)
{
    var internalMenu = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
    var d = internalMenu.style.display;
    if (d != "block") {
        internalMenu.style.display = "block";
        obj.innerHTML =
            '<IMG SRC="/images/menu-arrow-open.gif"'
            + ' border=0>&nbsp;' + title;
    } else {
        internalMenu.style.display = "none";
        obj.innerHTML =
            '<IMG SRC="/images/menu-arrow.gif" ' +
            'border=0>&nbsp;' + title;
    }
}
```

I have been searching Google, but I haven't found any solution yet.I've seen a method called **`ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript`**, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Is it possible to click that image button and take whatever results I want?

Comment: Does the button work without the image on it?

Comment: Which is the part of Excel in this case? If the VBA is running in Excel, how do you get the `el`? Are you sure you have the right element? Is the <input type="image"> a FORM's submit button? If so, why not simply submit the FORM?

Comment: Im sure about that .. i able to loop though each input element in the web page . i did inspect element for that button. and i pasted the html content in my question

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector**

No need for a loop. Use a CSS selector of:

```
input[src='/img/go_button.gif']
```

This specifies `input` tag with attribute `src` having value `'/img/go_button.gif'`

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply CSS selector using `.querySelector` method of document

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[src='/img/go_button.gif']").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

A. Get all the input elements in the page:

```
Set allInputs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

B. Looping through them and clicking the one which refers to the image "go":

```
For Each element In allInputs
    If element.getAttribute("src") = "/img/go_button.gif" Then
        element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next element
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it doesnt't worked. i already tried this method .But no luck ..code simply passes that line (el.click) :(

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[type="image"]').trigger('click');`

should do it